# Getting the class of the components of an array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

If I have

```
public <T> doSomething(T[] array)
{
}
```

how can I get `T.class` from `array`?

If I do `array.getClass()` that gets me `T[].class` instead.

Comment: (Note, [even if non-`null`] the array could be `String[]` giving `String.class`, but `T` could be `CharSequence`. Both reference arrays and reflection is best avoided.

Comment: "reflection is best avoided": sure, but in my case T is an Enum, and I'm taking in a T[], doing some calculation and returning an EnumMap<> which needs a Class<T> as a constructor parameter.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

### Component Type

Use this:

```
array.getClass().getComponentType()
```

> Returns the `Class` representing the
>   component type of an array. If this
>   class does not represent an array
>   class this method returns `null`.

**Reference:**

- [`Class.getComponentType()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType%28%29)

---

### Safe / Unsafe casting

> Is there a way I can cast to Class
>   from Class returned by
>   getComponentType() without getting a
>   compiler warning?

take this method:

```
public <T> void doSomething(final T[] array) throws Exception{
    final Class<? extends Object[]> arrayClass = array.getClass();
    final Class<?> componentType = arrayClass.getComponentType();
    final T newInstance = (T) componentType.newInstance();
}
```

Here's the generated byte code:

```
public void doSomething(java.lang.Object[] array) throws java.lang.Exception;
     0  aload_1 [array]
     1  invokevirtual java.lang.Object.getClass() : java.lang.Class [21]
     4  astore_2 [arrayClass]
     5  aload_2 [arrayClass]
     6  invokevirtual java.lang.Class.getComponentType() : java.lang.Class [25]
     9  astore_3 [componentType]
    10  aload_3 [componentType]
    11  invokevirtual java.lang.Class.newInstance() : java.lang.Object [30]
    14  astore 4 [newInstance]
    16  return
```

As you can see, the parameter type is erased to Object[], so the compiler has no way to know what T is. Yes, the compiler could use `array.getClass().getComponentType()`, but that would sometimes fail miserably because you can do stuff like this:

```
Object[] arr = new String[] { "a", "b", "c" };
Integer[] integerArray = (Integer[]) arr;
doSomething(integerArray);
```

(In this case `array.getClass().getComponentType()` returns `String.class`, but `T` stands for `Integer`. Yes, this is legal and does not generate compiler warnings.)

Comment: cool, thanks. Is there a way I can cast to Class<T> from Class<?> returned by getComponentType() without getting a compiler warning?

Comment: @Jason S: I don't think there is a way to do that, because the compiler won't know what to cast to.

Comment: yes, but `Class<T>` is just `Class` after type erasure, I guess.

Comment: sure, I understand the runtime issue, but the whole point of generics is that the compiler knows at compile time what types things are before the erasure step.

Comment: ahhhhhh... cool, thanks for the detailed discussion and the counterexample. I forgot arrays are covariant (? did I get the vocab right) so that a String[] is also an Object[]. lots of +1's....

Comment: can you get array length somehow? if you do not have access to the original object?

Comment: @voho unfortunately not without knowing whether it's a primitive or object array. Because you need to cast it to the array type and do arr.length on that

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this for multi-dimensional arrays the following recursive code will work

```
public static Class<?> getArrayType(Object array) {
    Object element = Array.get(array, 0);
    if (element.getClass().isArray()) {
        return getArrayType(element);
    } else {
        return array.getClass().getComponentType();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an old thread, but I would like to share a tested version I did with all your recomendations:

```
    @NotNull
    @SafeVarargs
    public static <T> T coalesce(@NotNull T ... args) {
        for(T i : args) {
            if(i != null) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        T newInstance = null;
        try {
            final Class<? extends Object[]> arrayClass = args.getClass();
            final Class<?> componentType = arrayClass.getComponentType();
            newInstance = (T) componentType.newInstance();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return newInstance;
    }
```

Hope will be usefull to you!

Best regards!

Comment: Now try writing a method `<T> T get() { return coalesce(); }` and calling it like `String s = get();`. [Oops.](https://ideone.com/8Im2NB)