# How to cast an java Object to its own getComponentType?

Tags: java, arrays, casting

I've a Class containing a private list of objects.

```
private List<Object> mylist;
```

Additionally my class contains two methods:

**(1)** addObject

```
public void addObject(Object obj)
{
    this.mylist.add(obj);
}
```

**(2)** dropObject

dropObject is a bit tricky. I want do drop the first element from `mylist` that is equal (but not the same) to the parameter `obj`. Therefore I compare the class of the parameter `obj` to every element's class in `mylist`. If the class of the current element matches, I want to compare, whether both elements are equal (but not the same).

Here I've got some problem to compare arrays with each other. I'd like to use `Array.deepEquals()` which requires a typecast for both `obj` and `curr_obj`.

So here's my code:

```
public void dropArgument(Object obj) {

    if (obj == null) {
        return;
    }

    Object objRemove = null;

    for (Object curr_obj : this.mylist) {
        
        if (curr_obj.getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            continue;
        }

        // primitive data type comparison
        if (obj.getClass().isPrimitive() && curr_obj == obj) {
            objRemove = curr_obj;
        } 
        // array comparison
        else if ((obj.getClass().isArray())
                /* the following line gives me headache */
                && (Arrays.deepEquals((Object[]) curr_obj, (Object[]) obj))) {
            objRemove = curr_obj;
        }
        // wrapper / collection comparison
        else if (curr_obj.equals(obj)) {
            objRemove = curr_obj;
        }
        // comparison of any other classes which are assumed not to have an 'equals' method.
        else {
            Field[] fInputFields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            Field[] fFields = curr_obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            if (Arrays.deepEquals(fInputFields, fFields)) {
                objRemove = curr_obj;
            }
        }
    }

    // delete obj match if found
    if (objRemove != null) {
        this.mylist.remove(objRemove);
    }
}
```

I wrote tests for this method and every type of array get's the following (stackstrace of an int[] array):

```
error:
java.lang.ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
    at javafxTablePane.FieldMethodData.dropArgument(FieldMethodData.java:119)
    at tests.DropArgumentsTests.test_dropMultiArrayInteger(DropArgumentsTests.java:345)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

The error is clear: `int[]` can't be typecasted to `Object[]`. So my question is, as `Array.deepEquals()` requires a typecast, how can I re-cast my objects to their own class/data type as array?

I searched for this and found the `getClass().getComponentType()` method with delivers the array type of my object. But I don't know (if even possible) how to use that to typecast `obj` to its own array-type.

**Some additional infos:**

1. I want to use `Object obj` as parameter for my method to be able to get any object independent of class or data type.
2. I am aware, that I could simply overload my method to handle each data type itself. But I try to solve this generic.

## Update

I've followed Darshan Mehta's suggestion and implemented a simple method that converts 1 dimensional arrays from primitive to wrapper classes. I can continue developing more generic code (e.g. casting arrays of any dimension) with that, so this solution fits my issue. I have put my code here for those who are interested.

```
/**
 * <b>ArrayEquals</b>
 * <p>
 * Compares two arrays of any same class and delivers their equality as boolean.
 * </p>
 * 
 * @param obj1
 *            [Object] : any object of any class as Object
 * @param obj2
 *            [Object] : any object of the same class as obj1 as Object
 * @return [boolean] : Equality of obj1 and obj2
 */
private boolean ArrayEquals(Object obj1, Object obj2) {

    Class<?> cObj1 = obj1.getClass().getComponentType();

    // convert byte[] to Byte[]
    if (cObj1.equals(byte.class)) {

        byte[] tmpObj1 = (byte[]) obj1;
        byte[] tmpObj2 = (byte[]) obj2;
        if (tmpObj1.length != tmpObj2.length) {
            return false;
        }
        Byte[] newObj1 = new Byte[tmpObj1.length];
        Byte[] newObj2 = new Byte[tmpObj2.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < tmpObj1.length; i++) {
            newObj1[i] = tmpObj1[i]; // Autoboxing
            newObj2[i] = tmpObj2[i]; // Autoboxing
        }
        return Arrays.deepEquals(newObj1, newObj2);
    }
    // convert short[] to Short[]
    else if (cObj1.equals(short.class)) {
        short[] tmpObj1 = (short[]) obj1;
        short[] tmpObj2 = (short[]) obj2;
        if (tmpObj1.length != tmpObj2.length) {
            return false;
        }
        Short[] newObj1 = new Short[tmpObj1.length];
        Short[] newObj2 = new Short[tmpObj2.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < tmpObj1.length; i++) {
            newObj1[i] = tmpObj1[i]; // Autoboxing
            newObj2[i] = tmpObj2[i]; // Autoboxing
        }

        return Arrays.deepEquals(newObj1, newObj2);
    }
    // convert int[] to Integer[]
    else if (cObj1.equals(int.class)) {
        Integer[] newObj1 = Arrays.stream((int[]) obj1).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
        Integer[] newObj2 = Arrays.stream((int[]) obj2).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
        return Arrays.deepEquals(newObj1, newObj2);
    }
    // convert long[] to Long[]
    else if (cObj1.equals(long.class)) {
        Long[] newObj1 = Arrays.stream((long[]) obj1).boxed().toArray(Long[]::new);
        Long[] newObj2 = Arrays.stream((long[]) obj2).boxed().toArray(Long[]::new);
        return Arrays.deepEquals(newObj1, newObj2);
    }
    // convert float[] to Float[]
    else if (cObj1.equals(float.class)) {
        float[] tmpObj1 = (float[]) obj1;
        float[] tmpObj2 = (float[]) obj2;
        if (tmpObj1.length != tmpObj2.length) {
            return false;
        }
        Float[] newObj1 = new Float[tmpObj1.length];
        Float[] newObj2 = new Float[tmpObj2.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < tmpObj1.length; i++) {
            newObj1[i] = tmpObj1[i]; // Autoboxing
            newObj2[i] = tmpObj2[i]; // Autoboxing
        }

        return Arrays.deepEquals(newObj1, newObj2);
    }
    // convert double[] to Double[]
    else if (cObj1.equals(double.class)) {
        double[] tmpObj1 = (double[]) obj1;
        double[] tmpObj2 = (double[]) obj2;
        if (tmpObj1.length != tmpObj2.length) {
            return false;
        }
        Double[] newObj1 = new Double[tmpObj1.length];
        Double[] newObj2 = new Double[tmpObj2.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < tmpObj1.length; i++) {
            newObj1[i] = tmpObj1[i]; // Autoboxing
            newObj2[i] = tmpObj2[i]; // Autoboxing
        }

        return Arrays.deepEquals(newObj1, newObj2);
    }
    // convert boolean[] to Boolean[]
    else if (cObj1.equals(boolean.class)) {
        boolean[] tmpObj1 = (boolean[]) obj1;
        boolean[] tmpObj2 = (boolean[]) obj2;
        if (tmpObj1.length != tmpObj2.length) {
            return false;
        }
        Boolean[] newObj1 = new Boolean[tmpObj1.length];
        Boolean[] newObj2 = new Boolean[tmpObj2.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < tmpObj1.length; i++) {
            newObj1[i] = tmpObj1[i]; // Autoboxing
            newObj2[i] = tmpObj2[i]; // Autoboxing
        }

        return Arrays.deepEquals(newObj1, newObj2);
    }
    // convert char[] to Character[]
    else if (cObj1.equals(char.class)) {
        char[] tmpObj1 = (char[]) obj1;
        char[] tmpObj2 = (char[]) obj2;
        if (tmpObj1.length != tmpObj2.length) {
            return false;
        }
        Character[] newObj1 = new Character[tmpObj1.length];
        Character[] newObj2 = new Character[tmpObj2.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < tmpObj1.length; i++) {
            newObj1[i] = tmpObj1[i]; // Autoboxing
            newObj2[i] = tmpObj2[i]; // Autoboxing
        }
        return Arrays.deepEquals(newObj1, newObj2);
    }
    // is no primitive
    else {
        return Arrays.deepEquals((Object[]) obj1, (Object[]) obj2);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `if (obj.equals(curr_obj) { objRemove = curr_obj;} ` ?

Comment: Arrays can't be compared with that. an `int[] iArr1 = {0,1,2}` won't match `int[] iArr2 = {0,1,2}` with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are comparing two objects, you should do the following:

- Extract out the comparison logic into a new method (e.g. `private boolean equals(Object o1, Object o2)` and call it from your `dropObject` method).
- For Array type, get component type using `array.getClass().getComponentType()` method call and try to cast it in an appropriate array. Casting an `int` array to `Object` array will throw `ClassCastException`. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737598/java-getting-the-class-of-the-components-of-an-array) SO answer for more explanation on casting and array type.
- If a component type is an array, implement the logic to iterate over all the elements and call `equals` method for each element.

Comment: Less code massive then completly overload my method. I'll give it a try!

Comment: Casting `Integer[]` to `Object[]` will not result in an exception.  However, casting `int[]` to `Object[]` will.